# How would I model a load bearing brick wall supported on a beam in FEM

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, reinforced-concrete

I have a continuous beam supported on columns. I need the brickwork above to act as load bearing wall for the next floor above. How would I model this in a FEM suite like SUMO (Prokon) ?

In SUMO I can insert concrete shear walls, but no brick walls. Since brick walls offer no tensile restraint, I can't use concrete shear walls.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SUMO. However, modelling of brick/masonry walls is often done using the [Discrete Element Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method). It looks like Prokon does have a [masonry design module](https://www.prokon.com/design/masonry-design), don't know if this would suit your needs.

Comment: Masonry design deals with masonry in isolation. I want to see how the wall behaves as a member in the structure as a whole.